# How to get new results on each execution of Search function in YouTube data API

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-data-api

I am working with a YouTube Script in Google Apps Scripts 
I am using the search function to get the results using keywords
but on each execution I am getting the same result as output I need new results or the result should not be duplicated. This is my current script:

(after getting search query and need to get the full description by using this code section YouTube.Videos.list)

```
/**getting Videos from Youtube with IDs**/

function searchByKeyword(){

  var results = YouTube.Search.list("id,snippet", {q : "trailers", maxResults: "10",type: "video"});
    Logger.log(' search results: %s', results.items);

  for(var i in results.items) {
    var item = results.items[i];
    Logger.log("[%s] Title: %s", item.id.videoId, item.snippet.title);
  }
  var item = results.items[i];
 //videosListById(item2.id.videoId)

  var results = YouTube.Videos.list("id,snippet",{'id': item.id.videoId });
  for(var i in results.items) {
    var item = results.items[i];
    Logger.log('%s Description: %s', item.snippet.title, item.snippet.description);


}

  for(var i in results.item) {
    var item = results.item[i];

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination)

The code below demonstrates how to use pagination within recursion.

- Max count set to 10 items
- Pagination size is 1

Change this if you need.

```
/**
 * @file getting Videos from Youtube with IDs
 */

/* exported userActionRun */

/**
 * User action. Runs the snippet
 */
function userActionRun() {
  var data = [];
  var res = searchByKeyword_('trailers');
  while (res.items.length && data.length < 10) {
    data = data.concat(res.items);
    res = searchByKeyword_('trailers', res.nextPageToken);
  }
  Logger.log(data.length);
  Logger.log(
    '\n%s',
    data
      .map(function(item, i) {
        return Utilities.formatString('%s. %s', i + 1, item.snippet.title);
      })
      .join('\n')
  );
}

/**
 * Returns YouTube search result
 * @param {string} keyword
 * @param {string} nextPageToken
 * @returns {object}
 */
function searchByKeyword_(keyword, nextPageToken) {
  var q = { q: keyword, maxResults: '1', type: 'video' };
  if (nextPageToken) q.pageToken = nextPageToken;

  var results = YouTube.Search.list('id,snippet', q);
  return results;
}
```

Comment: Hello @oshliaer I am getting 10 results but it is same as before in each execution , which i got in my script and also its exhaust  the api limit with 2 or 3 searches . So is it possible to  store the results in the script itself and pass it through each execution .1 by 1 or by some loop . like in first execution get 50 results and take the result one by one .

Comment: We need a DB to store the page  token updated answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54821144/how-to-get-different-results-in-each-execution-in-youtube-api-using-pagination/55095830#55095830